# Is It possible to integrate Python Seaborn with plotly

Tags: python, plot, data-visualization, seaborn, plotly

I am looking for some guidance in python seaborn for plot.ly. Is it possible to have seaborn graphs on plot.ly ?

Any example or tutorial available ? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see three examples in [this IPython NB](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/msund/11349097#IV.-Plotting-with-seaborn).

Comment: Thank you so much for the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seaborn is based on matplotlib, and Plotly converts the matplotlib figures it can (where mpl figure obejcts expose sufficient information to make the conversion. Here are the mpl conversion docs: https://plot.ly/matplotlib/)

Full coverage won't be available until mpl 2.0 release, when mpl figure objects are planned to be fully serializable.

Comment: I'd pump the brakes on that expectation. The 2.0 release's will primary purpose is to make the new aesthetics available. Full serialization is a large task and will probably take a bit more time.

Comment: I am following the same. But I am facing problem in annotations. When a mouse pointer is over a certain section it shows annotations but when see the same plot from a phone or tab it shows no annotations. Looking for that solutions so asked for seaborn options.